# Change variable value on input key press on Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

What I want to do is update the variable value when the user press a key, but it only update the value on blur of the input.

The following code is not working.

```
<p>@increment</p>
<input 
    type="text"
    @onchange="@((ChangeEventArgs e) =>
        increment = e.Value.ToString())"
/>

@code {
    string increment;
}
```

Using `@bind` and `@bind-value` also doesn't work.

I made a [blazorfiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/0f4m8y06) with the example.

Who can I make the value of my variable to change when the a key is pressed?

Comment: Use the `input` event instead of the `change` event.

Comment: @Dai How would that be?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

## Answer:

Quoting [Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0) docs:

```
<input @bind="CurrentValue" 
       @bind:event="oninput" />
```

> Unlike `onchange`, which fires when the element loses focus, `oninput` fires when the value of the text box changes.

## Using @oninput:

You can achieve it without `@bind` directive:

```
<input value="@CurrentValue"
       @oninput="(e)=> CurrentValue = e.Value.ToString()"/>
```

## `InputText` & `oninput`

To people that are looking for `oninput` with `InputText` component the answer is full documented on [InputText based on the input event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#inputtext-based-on-the-input-event) doc:

> Use the InputText component to create a custom component that uses the input event instead of the change event. `Shared/CustomInputText.razor`:

```
@inherits InputText

<input @attributes="AdditionalAttributes" class="@CssClass" 
    @bind="CurrentValueAsString" @bind:event="oninput" />
```

> The `CustomInputText` component can be used anywhere `InputText` is used:

```
<CustomInputText @bind-Value="exampleModel.Name" />
```

Comment: Form validation stops working if you don't use the components, `InputText` for instance. It seems either I lose validation or I lose the ability to have the binding updated if I keep validation.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan, full documented how to [InputText based on the input event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#inputtext-based-on-the-input-event) I updated the answer accordingly. Sorry about delay, I saw your comment today.

Answer (score 4):

In .NET 5 Blazor, `@oninput` seems to work fine directly on `InputText`:

```razor
<InputText @oninput="(e) => StringProp = e.Value.ToString()"></InputText>
```

So, thankfully, enabling the Submit button on forms right when they become touched is also possible without custom components. E.g.:

```razor
<InputText @oninput="() => untouched = false"></InputText>
...
<button type="submit" disabled="@untouched">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone wants to do this with the `InputText` form component provided create your own component file, eg `InputTextOnInput.razor`:

```
@inherits InputText

<input @attributes="AdditionalAttributes" class="@CssClass" 
   @bind="CurrentValueAsString" @bind:event="oninput" />
```

Then use it in your form like so:

```
<InputTextOnInput @bind-Value="@PropertyToUpdate " />

@code {
    private string PropertyToUpdate { get; set; }
}
```

More details on the [Blazor docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#inputtext-based-on-the-input-event)

Answer (score 1):

Following the recommendations from this thread, I used both oninput and onchange, and got my textbox to work even inside a table where each record is represented as r. It goes like this:

```
<td><input type="number" value="@r.SequenceNbr" @oninput="(e) => NewSeqNbr = e.Value.ToString()" @onchange="() => ChangeSeqNbr(r.Id)" ></td>
```

And in the code, I have:

```
     public string NewSeqNbr { get; set; }


private async Task ChangeSeqNbr(int recId)
    {
        .....
        // NewSeqNbr is available here 
        .....
    }
```