# Blazor Server Side race condition with form fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have an issue where a radio button selection is reset immediately after clicking it.

I have the following fields in a form:

[image]

I *think* what's happening is:

1. The user types a value into the input
2. The user then clicks a radio option (whilst having focus in the text input)
3. This click triggers the onChange/bind event for the text input to fire server side
4. For a brief moment, the user see's their radio option selected
5. Presumably when the server responds from the input's onChange event, it re-renders the radio button with the state it received at the time - i.e. no radio selection

Code:

```html
<InputText @bind-Value="_viewModel.Amount"></InputText>
<InputRadioGroup @bind-Value="_viewModel.SelectedOptionId" Name="name">
    @foreach (var option in _viewModel.RadioOptions)
    {
        <InputRadio Name="name" Value="@option.Id.ToString()" />
        <text>&nbsp;</text>@option.Name<br>
    }
</InputRadioGroup>
```

How do you prevent this?

Comment: The state of the radio button is probably related to some binded bool  property. If it is reset after input's event update, I guess this probably means there is no related update of the state of the binded property and it is subsequently reinitiazied. If you provide the definitions of the radio buttons it probably will become clearer what went wrong.

Comment: @AngelDinev I've updated the question to include the radio buttons

Comment: <InputRadioGroup ... @bind-Value="CurrentValue"... I'm missing the place, where this binded model property is set/defined.

Comment: It's in the usage `@bind-Value="_viewModel.SelectedRadioId"`

Comment: I've tested it with a standard `InputRadioGroup` and it has the same issue, so I don't think the radio control is the issue but rather how the onchange event is handled for the text input

Comment: Second thoughts, I'm getting the same issue with plain InputText and InputRadioGroup

Comment: I recommend creating a custom InputText component as referenced in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58222738/548997). That way you can update your model on input rather than on change which should hopefully resolve the issue with the radio button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there is an issue with the `InputRadioGroup` control.

[This GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39145#issuecomment-999779245) describes the problem.

> Basically, it will always rebuild its internals (So in your case the InputRadio components) due to an always-changing Key, resulting in the same kind of race condition as above.

The suggested workaround (which worked) is to implement a custom InputRadioGroup with the following added behaviour:

```
 public class MyInputRadioGroup<TValue> : InputRadioGroup<TValue>
 {
     private string? _name;
     private string? _fieldClass;

     protected override void OnParametersSet()
     {
         var fieldClass = EditContext?.FieldCssClass(FieldIdentifier) ?? string.Empty;
         if (fieldClass != _fieldClass || Name != _name)
         {
             _fieldClass = fieldClass;
             _name = Name;
             base.OnParametersSet();
         }
     }
 }
```

I believe this will be addressed in .NET 7 as per [this pull request](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/40148)

Answer (score 1):

What is happening here is that you bind to the wrong type.

I assume that both RadioOption.Id and SelectedOptionId are of type `int`.

That is fine, but then don't convert the Options' Ids to something else. It will hinder binding to the Selected value.

```
   <InputRadio Name="name" Value="@option.Id.ToString()" />  -- wrong
   <InputRadio Name="name" Value="@option.Id" />  -- ok
```

Comment: Yep, I was just going to suggest that. The mistyping definitely could prevent bidirectional binding.

Comment: Meant <InputRadioGroup> selected value, not the <InputRadio> items. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Tested it thoroughly - if the **type** of model property and radio values **match**, no matter int or string - works perfectly. If they are different, e.g. model prop is of type int and radio button value specified as string, then the (d)effect is what David described.

Comment: Actually, `SelectedOptionId` is a string, hence the `.ToString()`.