# Blazor real time search functionality

Tags: blazor

I am building a blazor to-do component,and when I search for an item I need to press enter or to unfocus the input in order to work

I am a beginner with blazor and I tried to make it work with binding but I can't get it to work,I have worked with Vue before and it's just not the same for me.

```cs
<input class="form-control" type="text" @bind="SearchItem" placeholder="search item" /> 
<ul> 
@foreach (var item in FilteredItems) 
{ 
<li>@item</li> 
} 
</ul> 

private string? SearchItem { get; set; } 
private List<string> FilteredItems { 
get 
{ 
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SearchItem)) 
{ 
   return ItemsList.ToList(); 
} 
else 
{ 
  return ItemsList.Where(x => x.Contains(SearchItem)).ToList(); 
}
}
```

Comment: here is the code:
    <input class="form-control" type="text" @bind="SearchItem"   placeholder="search item" /> 
   <ul>
        @foreach (var item in FilteredItems)
        {
            <li>@item</li>
        }
    </ul>
    private string? SearchItem { get; set; }
   private List<string> FilteredItems
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SearchItem))
            {
                return ItemsList.ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return ItemsList.Where(x => x.Contains(SearchItem)).ToList();
}

Comment: Post the code in the question itself. What you seem to ask is how to search on any keystroke, not any kind of real-time search. Just like Vue or React, you need to update the state on keystroke events, not on focus or form submission.

Comment: I've added the code to the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change variable value on input key press on Blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58222480/change-variable-value-on-input-key-press-on-blazor)

Comment: The event you need to handle is `oninput`, no matter what framework you use. As the duplicate shows, you can use `@bind:event="oninput"` to automatically update state on input changes

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple demo showing two ways to use binding and updating on each keystroke.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<div class="bg-secondary p-3 m-2">

    <input class="form-control" type="text" @bind="_searchString" @bind:event="oninput" @bind:after="this.UpdateSearch" />

    <ul class="m-3 bg-white">
        @foreach (var item in _selectedCountries)
        {
            <li>@item</li>
        }
    </ul>

    <div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
        <pre>Search String: @_searchString</pre>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="bg-secondary p-3 m-2">

    <input class="form-control" type="text" @bind="_searchString2" @bind:event="oninput" />

    <ul class="m-3 bg-white">
        @foreach (var item in _selectedCountries2)
        {
            <li>@item</li>
        }
    </ul>

    <div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
        <pre>Search String: @_searchString2</pre>
    </div>

</div>

@code {
    private string? _searchString;
    private string? _searchString2;

    private IEnumerable<string> _selectedCountries = Enumerable.Empty<string>();

    private IEnumerable<string> _selectedCountries2 => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_searchString2)
        ? Enumerable.Empty<string>()
        : _countries.Where(item => item.Contains(_searchString2 ?? string.Empty, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

    private List<string> _countries = new() { "France", "Spain", "Portugal", "United Kingdom" };

    private void UpdateSearch()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_searchString))
        {
            _selectedCountries = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
            return;
        }

        _selectedCountries = _countries.Where(item => item.Contains(_searchString ?? string.Empty, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
    }
}
```

[image]